# remove the gap between columns of result in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i have a query which gives me exact result.
but my issue is in result it gives me lot of gap between two columns like

```
col1                                                                     col2                                              col3
----                                                                     ----                                              ----
```

when i have checked the length of individual columns with `length` function they are showing just 4 or 5 is the length .

i have used some windowing functions to calculate those columns and aliased them.

My question is why it is showing the result as such and how to eliminate the gap b/w the columns in the result?

I am using `ORACLE10G`

Comment: Just to verify: are you running this through SQLPlus?

Comment: Ya !! i am using SQL*Plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLPlus `COLSEP` setting controls what's displayed between columns. Try this:

```
SET COLSEP ' '
```

That's the default. You can set it to any value you want.

If you want to control the width of a column in SQLPlus, it's normally done through the `COLUMN` setting, which matches by column name. This will format column `col1` to be 20 characters wide, regardless of the column's value:

```
COLUMN col1 FORMAT A20
```

Note that if the `col1` value is longer than 20 characters, it will wrap.

---

- [SQLPlus v10.2 reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm)
- [SQLPlus v11.2 reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/qstart.htm)
- [SET COLSEP (v10.2)](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html)
- [SET COLSEP (v11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698758)

Comment: But can you please tell me what is this `COLSEP`

Comment: Sorry @Aspirant, I should have included a link. `SET COLSEP` is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#sthref2716). You can also experiment: try `SET COLSEP '-+-'` then a `SELECT` statement: you'll see `-+-` between each column of the results. Then reset as above using `SET COLSEP ' '`.